# Get value from raster layer QGIS according x,y point on mouse click

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have this code to read data from raster layer QGIS  in var u1  I put the value from read raster layer but x and y put it manually by QgsPointXY(454755, 3910940) now I want the x,y value by mouse click to raster layer.

```
  layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
  val, res = layer.dataProvider().sample(QgsPointXY(454755, 3910940), 1)
  u1=val

  self.dlg.textBrowser.clear()
  if self.dlg.radioButton.clicked:
      ch=1
  elif self.dlg.radioButton_2.clicked:
       ch=2
    
  Q=float(self.dlg.lineEdit.text())
  H=float(self.dlg.lineEdit_3.text())
       
  def equation1(list2):
      ly=float(list2[2]*math.pow(x,list2[3]))
      lz=float(list2[0]*math.pow(x,list2[1]))
      C=(Q/(math.pi*u1*ly*lz))*math.exp(-0.5*(math.pow((H/lz),2)))      
      return(self.dlg.textBrowser.append(format(C)))

  if (ch==1):
      for x in arange(0,10,0.1):
       if (0 < x <= 0.2 ):list1=[90.673,0.93198,18.333,1.8096];equation1(list1);
       elif  (0.2 < x <= 0.4 ):list1=[98.483,0.98332,18.333,1.8096];equation1(list1)
       elif  (0.4 < x < 5 ):list1=[109.3,1.0971,18.333,1.8096];equation1(list1)
       elif  (x >= 5):lz=5000;ly=5000;C=Q/(math.pi*u1*ly*lz)*math.exp(-0.5*(pow((H/lz),2)))
 
  elif (ch==2):
     for x in arange(0,10,0.1): 
      if (0 < x <= 0.2):list1=[61.141,0.91465,12.5,1.857];equation1(list1)
      elif  (0.2 < x <= 0.4 ):list1=[61.141,0.91465,12.5,1.857];equation1(list1)
      elif  (0.4 < x < 5):list1=[61.141,0.91465,12.5,1.857];equation1(list1)  
      elif  (x >= 5):lz=5000;ly=5000;C=Q/(math.pi*u1*ly*lz)*math.exp(-0.5*(pow((H/lz),2)))    
  else:
   self.dlg.textBrowser.append("Sorry you must choose Select Stability Classes of Pasquill ")*
```

Answer (score 4):

You can adapt following PyQGIS code in your plugin (see corresponding comment for guidance).

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint

def display_point( pointTool ): # function before run method as display_point(self, point, button)
    x = pointTool[0]
    y = pointTool[1]
    
    print(x, y)

    raster = iface.activeLayer()

    provider = raster.dataProvider()
    extent = raster.extent()
    xSize = raster.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
    ySize = raster.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = extent.toRectF().getCoords()
    row = int((ymax - y)/ySize)
    col = int((x - xmin)/xSize)
    
    print(row, col)
    
    value = provider.identify(QgsPointXY(x, y), 
                              QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue).results()[1]
    
    print(value)

    
# a reference to our map canvas 
canvas = iface.mapCanvas() # in __init__ as self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()

# this QGIS tool emits as QgsPoint after each click on the map canvas
pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas) # in __init__ as self.pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.canvas)

pointTool.canvasClicked.connect( display_point ) # in initGui as self.pointTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.display_point)

canvas.setMapTool( pointTool ) # in run method as self.canvas.setMapTool(self.pointTool)
```

I tried above code in QGIS Python Console, as it can be observed in following image, and it worked as expected (corroborated with QGIS Value Tool plugin).

[image]

Comment: thanks , its helpful thank you